# How to extract the dynamic text 3204255 from the html provided through Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get number from div.When I execute my test cases new number is showing,now I want to get that number,or in other words to print it in a console.

I was using :

```
webElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'responsive now') and text()='Application number']"));
webelement.getText();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='responsive-show']")).getAttribute("value");
```

it is not compailining about locators ,but it did not show number.

```
<td> 
  <div class="responsive-show">Application number</div>
  "3204255" 
  <input data val="true" data-val-number="The field ExaminationNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The ExaminationNumber field is required." id="ActiveExamModeIs_0__ExaminationNumber" name="ActiveExamMode[0].ExaminationNumber" type="hidden" value="3204255"> 
  <input data -val="true" data-val-number="The field ExaminationEligibilityExamTypeId must be a number" data-val-required="The ExaminationEligibilityExamTypeId fiels is required." type="hidden" value="1">
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: to help you out better do not post images of code, please post your html code in text format.

Comment: Your first attempt might work, but you have "responsive now" instead of "responsive-show"

Comment: I fixed still ,not getting text

Comment: <div class "responsive-show">Application Number<div>==$0                           "3204255"

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of an image so that it's readable.

Comment: <td>==$0 <div class="responsive-show">Application number</div>"3204255" <input data val="true" data-val-number="The field ExaminationNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The ExaminationNumber field is required." id="ActiveExamModeIs_0__ExaminationNumber" name="ActiveExamMode[0].ExaminationNumber" type="hidden" value="3204255"> <input data -val="true" data-val-number="The field ExaminationEligibilityExamTypeId must be a number" data-val-required="The ExaminationEligibilityExamTypeId fiels is required." type="hidden" value="1">==$0 </td>

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the number i.e. **3204255** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* then you can use the `executeScript()` method as per the following solution:

- *Java* solution:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-hover']//tbody/tr/td")));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Long & Short of it: there is not a neat way of getting **text value** using simple Selenium functions unless you want to make use of **"JavascriptExecutor"**

Alternative option is getting the whole text from `<td>` element using simple selenium operations & then using String function `substring()` to get your Application number value which is jammed between quotes `"`.

**Code:**

```
    String input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td")).getAttribute("innerText");
    input = input.substring(input.indexOf("\"")+1, input.lastIndexOf("\""));
    System.out.println("Extracted Value" + input);
```

Answer (score 0):

text: 3204247 is not contained in div tag but its in `<td>`.
You can try this:

```
webElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td"));// you can improve this locator and can also use one below
//webElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='responsive-show']/..")); using xpath axes
String value=webelement.getText();// OR
//String value=webelement.getAttribute("innerText");
```

Comment: did not work for me,I tried add some wait time and it is also  did not work

Comment: is it possible that it might be hidden ?

Comment: Text you are looking for is not in div tag. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I do not have tr/td text                <td>==$0       <div class="responsive-show">Application number</div>"3204255"   <input data val="true" data-val-number="The field ExaminationNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The ExaminationNumber field is required." id="ActiveExamModeIs_0__ExaminationNumber" name="ActiveExamMode[0].ExaminationNumber" type="hidden" value="3204255"> <input data-val-required="The ExaminationEligibilityExamTypeId fiels is required."

Comment: I am having problem to locate tr/td .Can you help me pls.

Comment: ok, just to confirm again you are looking for text 3204255, right?

Comment: webElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr/td"));// did not fail but did not get value
//webElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='responsive-show']/preceding-sibling::td[1]"))// error unable to locate element

Comment: have you tried innerText with first locator? for second one my bad its not preceding but parent. updated answer

Comment: yes I tried with innerText and getText now second xpath passing but still not showing numbers

Comment: seems like webdriver is not helping in this case. You can try the javascript executor to extract the content as proposed by DebanjanB